# Nested function call in async way python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I have an api that returns response of pagination only 10 records at a time. I want to process 10 record (index=0 and limit=10) then next 10(index=10 and limit=10) and so on till it returns empty array.

I want to do it in async way.

I am using the following deps:

```
yarl==1.6.0
Mako==1.1.3
asyncio==3.4.3
aiohttp==3.6.2
```

The code is:

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(getData(id, token,0, 10))
logger.info("processed all data")



async def getData(id, token, index, limit):
    try:
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            response = await fetch_data_from_api(session, id, token, index, limit)
            if response == []:
                logger.info('Fetched all data')
            else:
                # process data(response)
                getData(session, id, limit, limit+10)
    except Exception as ex:
        raise Exception(ex)


async def fetch_data_from_api(
        session, id, token, index, limit
):
    try:
        url = f"http://localhost:8080/{id}?index={index}&limit={limit}"
        async with session.post(
                url=url,
                headers={"Authorization": token}
        ) as response:
            response.raise_for_status()
            response = await response.json()
            return json.loads(json.dumps(response))
    except Exception as ex:
        raise Exception(
            f"Exception {ex} occurred"
        )
```

I issue is that it works fine for first time but when i am calling the method getData(session, id, limit, limit+10) again from async def getData(id, token, index, limit). It is not been called.

How can i resolve the issue?

Comment: you need to await the call since its an async function

Comment: Python doesn't support function overloads, you cannot have two functions called `getData`. What happens is that `getData` calls itself in what would be infinite recursion except for the fact that the lack of `await` results in the inner `getData` never getting executed. To fix the issue, rename one of the `getData` functions and update the call sites.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues I see in your code.

First, and this is what you talk about, is the `getData` method.
It is unclear to me a bit by looking at the code, what is that "second" `getData`. In the function definition your arguments are `getData(id, token, index, limit)`, but when you call it from within the function you call it with `getData(session, id, limit, limit+10)` where the `id` is the second parameter. Is that intentional? This looks to me like there is another `getData` method, or it's a bug.

In case of the first option: (a) you probably need to show us that code as well, as it's important for us to be able to give you better responses, and (b), more importantly, it will not work. Python doesn't support overloading and the `getData` you are referencing from within the wrapping `getData` is the same wrapping method.

In case it's the second option: (a) you might have an issue with the function parameters, and (b) - you are missing an `await` before the `getData` (i.e. `await getData`). This is actually probably also relevant in case it's the "first option".

---

Other than that, your exception handling is redundant. You basically just re raise the exception, so I don't see any point in having the `try-catch` blocks. Even more, for some reason in the first method, you create an `Exception` from the base exception class (not to be confused with `BaseException`). Just don't have the `try` block.